# Multitasking Python-Arduino Communication

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, arduino

I am doing a project where I have to acquire data from an Arduino Uno connected to various sensors using Python on Windows (and eventually in Raspberry Pi 2 Model B).

As Python would constantly be listening to Arduino, I was thinking how should I let Python be always ready to read in a user input (any keyboard keys or even better, with a push-button if this is possible) after which Python will tell Arduino Uno to re-acquire data from all the sensors (i.e. refresh data from the sensors) and print it on the Python Console. I am currently using PyCharm with pySerial for communications between Arduino and Python. My code (without considering user input) is as of below:

```
import sys
import serial
import time

arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=1)

time.sleep(3) # wait for Arduino to initialize

def readData():  # reads inputs from Arduino
    try:
        datastring = arduino.readline()
        print datastring
    except:
        pass

while True:
    readData()

strin = 'p'
arduino.write(strin.encode())  # tell arduino a phase shifter setting has been finished
strin = 's'
arduino.write(strin.encode())

arduino.close()
time.sleep(0.5)  # waits for 0.5 s
# print('Data to be transfered: %s'%ASCIIdata)
```

I understand that related topics have been posted before, however, I have tried the solutions online to no avail and I am finding it quite difficult to code as I am very new to Python. (I am reading documentation and examples and trying to code at the moment.)

Currently, I have done some research on this topic and have tried the following methods but to no avail:

1. Using msvcrt, getch and using nodelay(1) to allow my program to run even when no user input is received. I used "stdscr", and curses, to which I used "stdscr = curses.initscr()", however, in PyCharm, as it is an IDE, it returned an error "Redirection is not supported." My attempt at implementing this is as of below:

   ```
   def readData():  # reads inputs from Arduino
       try:
           datastring = arduino.readline()
           print datastring
       except:
           pass

   while True:
       stdscr = curses.initscr()
       stdscr.nodelay(1)
       user_input = stdscr.getch()
       if user_input == -1:
           readData()
   ```
2. I understand there is multithreading in Python and a number of leads lead me to think that it should be the way to go if I want to listen to user inputs continuously while still acquiring data from Arduino. May I ask if this is the correct direction in which I should pursue?
3. I have heard about select() and poll() though the former isn't supported on Windows. I will try select() when I port my program over to Raspberry Pi which runs on Linux.

May I ask if anyone can point me to a direction on how to implement a program that reads data continuously from Arduino in PyCharm, and but a user input will cause everything to stop (like an interrupt) and have Python (PyCharm) ask Arduino to pass it a set of fresh sensor data?

Thank you! :)

Comment: More similar question/answer in stackowerflow(not all in one). Micro processors do not work like this(`readline()` . Communication will not be read by line, A data size is determined or the length of the data at the beginning of the package is necessarily written. Solution can't teach you anythings.

Comment: Thank you dsgdfg, for your guidance. (: May I ask if you can point me to any resources to learn about these? This is because I feel that I am lacking some thing however, there is no one to guide me along. For example, may I ask, in a serial communications line between Arduino and Python (which will be on Rpi in the end, though I am using Windows now), what is the "server" here? This is because some codes I saw online uses the word "server" but I am not sure how to define it when I plug my Arduino into my computer's USB port.

Comment: I am really sorry if I do not make any sense here. Thank you so so much for your guidance. (: